# Simplest way to add message after validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

What is best and simplest way to add message(**without refreshing page**) when I try to save something to database and validation fails?

Can I do it with flash message?

Comment: You need to understand Rails's Unobtrusive JavaScript. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: Have you tried using [Rails with AJAX](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)?

Comment: I am on it now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As the validations set in your models are server side you wont receive a flash messages until you submit the form. As suggested by others there might be a way of doing this using AJAX however you could use JavaScript to watch elements of your form and create flash messages of your own to validate on the client side.

HTML5 introduced new input attributes such as `required` and `pattern` that you could also use to validate value set in an `input` element.

EG `<input type="text" name="firstname" required />`

If someone tried to submit the form without putting a value in the firstname input a little error message would show up. No hard work here, nice.

The pattern attribute takes any regular expression as it's value so you can be as specific as you like as to what the value should be.

EG `<input type="text" name="firstname" pattern="^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,20}$" />`

This would only allow a 1-20 letter word beginning with a capital letter and display an error message on submit if not. (No server request is made).

I like this addition to HTML 5 and is a good way of doing client side validation. Server side validation in your models is most important as any client side validation can be avoided by a visitor turning off JavaScript in their browser or editing the page source.

You can use CSS to style the input box in different ways with these new attributes too.

EG `input:required:invalid { border: 1px solid red; }`

[Found this helpful resource here ›](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/)